# How to change API responseBody Message in WebFilter - Spring Flux

Tags: spring-webflux, webfiltering

Actual response:

"serviceMessage" :{
"code": 200
}

Expected response:

"message": {
"code":200
}

The response Message has to be changed in WebFilter Implementation. Since this API is Spring-Flux implementation, Filter Interface cannot be used.

How do i change responseBody? I see the options to change header, statusCode.

Comment: I'm assuming this response body is modelled using a java class in your code. Can you share the code to that class?